# What could be wrong with this example from an architectural point of view

Tags: python

What could be wrong with this example from an architectural point of view:

```
class Base(object):
    def say_hello(self):
        self.hello()

class Child1(Base):
    def hello(self):
        print 'Hello child 1'

class Child2(Base):
    def hello(self):
        print 'Hello child 2'

c = Child1()
c.say_hello()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, this is just a simplified example, there is nothing wrong with the approach. Moreover, it has a name: [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with it is that `say_hello` is pointless:  you should drop that, and just use `hello()` directly.  `say_hello` isn't giving you anything.

Comment: If however `say_hello` had contained more code either before or after calling `hello()` then you would have a perfectly good *template method* pattern only lacking a default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The base class does not have a `hello` method; potentially causing `say_hello` to break. There is no requirement to implement `hello` in a subclass, but then again: Python won't mind if you shoot yourself in the foot, that's just your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Child2` is obsolete - you never call it, `Base` references a child function implicitly, and `say_hello` is superfluous - it doesn't do anything apart from call `hello`.

Also - you're asking SO to answer your interview questions for you, that might be considered bad form.